# argocd app create in CI pipeline (GitHub Actions, Tekton, ...) throws "PermissionDenied desc = permission denied: applications, create, default/myapp"

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-deployment, argocd, tekton, gitops

From our Tekton pipeline we want to use ArgoCD CLI to do a `argocd app create` and `argocd app sync` dynamically based on the app that is build. We created a new user [as described in the docs](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/user-management/#create-new-user) by adding a `accounts.tekton: apiKey` to the `argocd-cm` ConfigMap:

```
kubectl patch configmap argocd-cm -n argocd -p '{"data": {"accounts.tekton": "apiKey"}}'
```

Then we created a token for the `tekton` user with:

```
argocd account generate-token --account tekton
```

With this token as the `password` and the `username` `tekton` we did the `argocd login` like

```
argocd login $(kubectl get service argocd-server -n argocd --output=jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].hostname}') --username=tekton --password="$TOKEN";
```

Now from within our Tekton pipeline (but we guess that would be the same for every other CI, given the usage of a non-admin user) we get the following error if we run `argocd app create`:

```
$ argocd app create microservice-api-spring-boot --repo https://gitlab.com/jonashackt/microservice-api-spring-boot-config.git --path deployment --dest-server https://kubernetes.default.svc --dest-namespace default --revision argocd --sync-policy auto
error rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = permission denied: applications, create, default/microservice-api-spring-boot, sub: tekton, iat: 2022-02-03T16:36:48Z
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is mentioned in [Argo's useraccounts docs](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/user-management/#local-usersaccounts-v15):

> When you create local users, each of those users will need additional
> RBAC rules set up, otherwise they will fall back to the default policy
> specified by policy.default field of the argocd-rbac-cm ConfigMap.

But these additional RBAC rules could be setup the simplest [using ArgoCD `Projects`](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/projects/). And with such a `AppProject` you don't even need to create a user like `tekton` in the ConfigMap `argocd-cm`. ArgoCD projects have the ability to define [Project roles](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/projects/#project-roles):

> Projects include a feature called roles that enable automated access to a project's applications. These can be used to give a CI pipeline a restricted set of permissions. For example, a CI system may only be able to sync a single app (but not change its source or destination).

There are 2 solutions how to configure the `AppProject`, role & permissions incl. role token:

1. using `argocd` CLI
2. using a manifest YAML file

### 1.) Use `argocd` CLI to create `AppProject`, role & permissions incl. role token

So let's get our hands dirty and create a ArgoCD `AppProject` using the `argocd` CLI called `apps2deploy`:

```
argocd proj create apps2deploy -d https://kubernetes.default.svc,default --src "*"
```

We create it with the `--src "*"` as a wildcard for any git repository ([as described here](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/5382#issue-799715045)).

Now we create a Project `role` called `create-sync` via:

```
argocd proj role create apps2deploy create-sync --description "project role to create and sync apps from a CI/CD pipeline"
```

You can check the new role has been created with `argocd proj role list apps2deploy`.

Then we need to create a token for the new Project role `create-sync`, which can be created via:

```
argocd proj role create-token apps2deploy create-sync
```

This token needs to be used for the `argocd login` command inside our Tekton / CI pipeline. There's also a `--token-only` parameter for the command, so we can create an environment variable via

```
ARGOCD_AUTH_TOKEN=$(argocd proj role create-token apps2deploy create-sync --token-only)
```

The `ARGOCD_AUTH_TOKEN` will be automatically used by `argo login`.

Now we need to give permissions to the role, so it will be able to create and sync our application in ArgoCD from within Tekton or any other CI pipeline. [As described in the docs we therefore add policies to our roles](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/projects/#project-roles) using the `argocd` CLI:

```sh
argocd proj role add-policy apps2deploy create-sync --action get --permission allow --object "*"
argocd proj role add-policy apps2deploy create-sync --action create --permission allow --object "*"
argocd proj role add-policy apps2deploy create-sync --action sync --permission allow --object "*"
argocd proj role add-policy apps2deploy create-sync --action update --permission allow --object "*"
argocd proj role add-policy apps2deploy create-sync --action delete --permission allow --object "*"
```

Have a look on the role policies with `argocd proj role get apps2deploy create-sync`, which should look somehow like this:

```
$ argocd proj role get apps2deploy create-sync
Role Name:     create-sync
Description:   project role to create and sync apps from a CI/CD pipeline
Policies:
p, proj:apps2deploy:create-sync, projects, get, apps2deploy, allow
p, proj:apps2deploy:create-sync, applications, get, apps2deploy/*, allow
p, proj:apps2deploy:create-sync, applications, create, apps2deploy/*, allow
p, proj:apps2deploy:create-sync, applications, update, apps2deploy/*, allow
p, proj:apps2deploy:create-sync, applications, delete, apps2deploy/*, allow
p, proj:apps2deploy:create-sync, applications, sync, apps2deploy/*, allow
JWT Tokens:
ID          ISSUED-AT                                EXPIRES-AT
1644166189  2022-02-06T17:49:49+01:00 (2 hours ago)  <none>
```

Finally we should have setup everything to do a successful `argocd app create`. All we need to do is to add the `--project apps2deploy` parameter:

```
argocd app create microservice-api-spring-boot --repo https://gitlab.com/jonashackt/microservice-api-spring-boot-config.git --path deployment --project apps2deploy --dest-server https://kubernetes.default.svc --dest-namespace default --revision argocd --sync-policy auto
```

### 2.) Use manifest YAML to create `AppProject`, role & permissions incl. role token

As all those CLI based steps in solution 1.) are quite many, we could also [using a manifest YAML file](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/projects/#configuring-rbac-with-projects). Here's an example `argocd-appproject-apps2deploy.yml` which configures exactly the same as in solution a):

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: AppProject
metadata:
  name: apps2deploy
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  destinations:
    - namespace: default
      server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
  sourceRepos:
    - '*'
  roles:
    - description: project role to create and sync apps from a CI/CD pipeline
      name: create-sync
      policies:
      - p, proj:apps2deploy:create-sync, applications, get, apps2deploy/*, allow
      - p, proj:apps2deploy:create-sync, applications, create, apps2deploy/*, allow
      - p, proj:apps2deploy:create-sync, applications, update, apps2deploy/*, allow
      - p, proj:apps2deploy:create-sync, applications, delete, apps2deploy/*, allow
      - p, proj:apps2deploy:create-sync, applications, sync, apps2deploy/*, allow
```

There are only 2 steps left to be able to do a successful `argocd app create` from within Tekton (or other CI pipeline). We need to `apply` the manifest with

```
kubectl apply -f argocd-appproject-apps2deploy.yml
```

And we need to need to create a role token, ideally assigning it directly to the `ARGOCD_AUTH_TOKEN` for the `argocd login` command (which also needs to be done afterwards):

```
ARGOCD_AUTH_TOKEN=$(argocd proj role create-token apps2deploy create-sync --token-only)
```

The same `argocd app create` command as mentioned in solution 1.) should work now:

```
argocd app create microservice-api-spring-boot --repo https://gitlab.com/jonashackt/microservice-api-spring-boot-config.git --path deployment --project apps2deploy --dest-server https://kubernetes.default.svc --dest-namespace default --revision argocd --sync-policy auto
```

Comment: im not sure you will see this but you did huge job here and i've tried to go by your little guide here but still got a permission denied.. 
If you could help me in my question it will be amazing! thank you! I will link my questing here -----> 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76863249/argocd-unable-to-create-application-permission-denied)