# Argocd Unable to create application: permission denied

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-deployment, argocd, gitops

I've been trying to make an application but keep getting this error.

[image: first picture]

[image: second picture]

**proj list:**

```
argocd proj list
NAME        DESCRIPTION  DESTINATIONS  SOURCES  CLUSTER-RESOURCE-WHITELIST  NAMESPACE-RESOURCE-BLACKLIST  SIGNATURE-KEYS
  ORPHANED-RESOURCES
argocd                   <none>        <none>   <none>                      <none>                        <none>          disabled
argocdtest               <none>        <none>   <none>                      <none>                        <none>          disabled
default                  *,*           *        */*                         <none>                        <none>
```

**Cluster list:**

```
argocd cluster list
SERVER                          NAME        VERSION  STATUS   MESSAGE                                                  PROJECT
https://kubernetes.default.svc  in-cluster           Unknown  Cluster has no applications and is not being monitored.
```

**Account list:**

```
argocd account list
NAME   ENABLED  CAPABILITIES
admin  true     login
```

what might be the problem? i've followed [Argocd Guide](https://%20https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started)

Answer (score 6):

I have this issue. It is fixed by using 'Project Name' : default.
The 'Project Name' default is a project, created during Argo CD installation and which has the right RBAC configured.
If you use another 'Project Name' than default, you need to add RBAC.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

ok this is a pure joke.

if someone gets this error........

**1st** - **don't** use Uppercase letters in the name.
use something like my-app
and not MyApp
why? I have no idea.

**2nd** - context might change to minikube or something else check it and change to your right config (kubectl config current-context)

**3rd** - remove extra steps (it worked for me)
make something like in [here](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/#creating-apps-via-cli/)
you can copy paste the way and change by your clusters and needs.
good luck.....